# accessing objects property dynamically (appending a string)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a loop like this in underscore

```
_.each(questions,function(data){

a="reason"+data.choosen;
%>

<%= data.a; %>

<%
count++;
});
 %>
```

The data.choosen gets either 1 or 2 or 3 or 4.
Now based on this i want to display the  data.reason1 or data.reason2 or data.reason3 or data.reason4 property of the data object.

I tried the above approach but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript

```
x.y
```

is equivalent to

```
x["y"]
```

so you can just change your code to

```
data[a]
```

Comment: if x.y is equivalent to x["y"] why do i need to change? It worked though !!

Comment: @beNerd: Note the double quotes. Accessing property with `x.y` requires using `x["y"]` and what you put between square brackets is an expression (and can be an expression, e.g the result of calling of a funcion). Of course using a fixed string inside brackets is rarely used (only for properties with names that are not valid Javascript identifiers). Using `data["a"]` for example would have been exactly as the code you wrote (and wouldn't work).